# BackgroundService not blocking start of application

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I have a background service in my net 7 web api application:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
            // do some work
            await Task.Delay(60000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Which I register like this:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
```

How can I make it blocking so that the rest of my application doesn't start before the first `do some work` is executed?

Comment: Move the // do some work code into a separate method so you can call it at startup.

Comment: @HansPassant how about implementing `IHostedService` instead, doing the initial work in `StartAsync` and then start a long running task at the end of the method for the polling?

Comment: Did you try putting the code you want to be blocking in the constructor?

Comment: @SelmirAljic Doing non construction work in a constructor is ill-advised.

Comment: @Kit I don't believe I gave any advice, I simply asked a question. Other than that I also don't agree with your statement for the following reasons: 

1. There are many examples of .net libraries which do initialization work in a constructor. 

2. We got an example of "// do some work" and have zero context whether that work is construction work or not. 

3. We don't know the context of the application, it might be a POC where generally code design or quality are not that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your application is wired. If you are using the default setup (for ASP.NET Core 7th version) then background services should be started up before the rest of the app and you can just override the `BackgroundService.StartAsync` (or just implement `IHostedService` directly) and perform first "*do some work code*" (potentially moving it to separate method) invocation in **blocking** manner (i.e. use blocking calls via `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait(...)` for async methods). Also do not forget to register this "blocking" hosted service first if you have multiple ones.

If you do not want to rely on the default order or you are using setup which has different order of startup (for example see [this](https://andrewlock.net/controlling-ihostedservice-execution-order-in-aspnetcore-3/#registering-ihostedservices-in-program-cs)) then I would recommend to move the "*do some work code*" in some service, resolve it and invoke it before the app run:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
// ...
var service = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>(); // create scope if needed
await service.DoSomeWorkCode(); // first run
app.Run();
```

P.S.

Also you can consider adding [readiness probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0#separate-readiness-and-liveness-probes) to your app and middleware which will intercept all other requests if app is not ready (i.e. the initial run of "*do some work code*" has not finished).

Answer (score 2):

Move the

// do some work code

into a separate method so you can call it at startup.